# Wipe Last Input From Onclick Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

I've been trying to wipe last input added in textarea by ONCLICK BUTTONS but don't seem to wipe last input instead it wipes all of onclick inputs.

Note, the button should be onclick as it variable changes dynamically.

```
<html>
<textarea id="Content" name="Content"></textarea>
<button class="AddTo" value="a">a</button>
<button class="AddTo" value="b">b</button>
<button class="AddTo" value="c">c</button>
<button class="Backspace" value="">backspace</button>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunctionY1();" class="list1" style="width:80px; background-color:red;" id="Y1">Y1</button>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunctionY2();" class="list1" style="width:80px; background-color:red;" id="Y2">Y2</button>

<script>
   function myFunctionY1() {
   document.getElementsByName("Content")[0].value += "Hello!";

   }

   function myFunctionY2() {
   document.getElementsByName("Content")[0].value += "Hi!";

   }
</script>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js"> </script>

<script>
var values = [];

$(function () {

    $('.AddTo').on('click', function () {
        values.push($(this).val());
        $('#Content').val(values.join(" "));
    });

    $('.Backspace').on('click', function () {
        values.pop();
        $('#Content').val(values.join(" "));
    });

});


</script>
```

Comment: That didn't work. Removing + will make it a fresh variable, it wouldn't append to what you have in the textarea. @WilsondeFreitasJr.

Comment: Actually works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/zkttph04/

Comment: The backspace should wipe only the last input not all, but when Y1 or Y2 is pressed it wipes everything out.

Comment: for me too. only red buttons don't work. but if u apply the same logic in this button like u did in 'a', 'b' e 'c' buttons, it will be fine.

Comment: Because you do not push them like a, b, c.

Comment: @Lain - can you see to that?

Comment: Lain is right...u r using two diferente ways to do the same thing...

Comment: @Reuben: Push the values like a, b, c, and it will work.

Comment: I'd have to use Onclick for Y1 and Y2 because their values are added dynamically. @WilsondeFreitasJr.

Comment: @Lain -------------

Comment: What do you mean by the values are added dynamically?

Comment: The value do not come from value=""

Comment: They are added from database. Via Onclick.

Comment: The whole buttons?

Comment: u can add value with jquery...like u r doing with js...

Comment: I mean, how ever you add the buttons and/or its value wont change your logic. You just keep pushing the buttons value and poping it to get it removed. Else you have to reconsider your button creation or how you add the values to those buttons.

Comment: I think this is what you need in the end: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Thanks for your help, Brothers! @Lain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do it:

```html
<html>
<textarea id="Content" name="Content"></textarea>
<button class="AddTo" value="a">a</button>
<button class="AddTo" value="b">b</button>
<button class="AddTo" value="c">c</button>
<button class="Backspace" value="">backspace</button>
<button type="button" class="list1" value="Hello!" style="width:80px; background-color:red;" id="Y1">Y1</button>
<button type="button" class="list1" value="Hi!" style="width:80px; background-color:red;" id="Y2">Y2</button>

</html>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js"> </script>

<script>
var values = [];

$(function () {


   $('#Y1').attr("value", "foo");
   $('#Y2').attr("value", "foo2");

    $('.AddTo').on('click', function () {
        values.push($(this).val());
        $('#Content').val(values.join(" "));
    });

    $('.Backspace').on('click', function () {
        values.pop();
        $('#Content').val(values.join(" "));
    });

     $('.list1').on('click', function () {
        values.push($(this).val());
        $('#Content').val(values.join(" "));
    });
});


</script>
```

Comment: change them to what pls? @Wilson

Comment: I think the OP is more concerned about the $('.Backspace') function not doing what it should.

Comment: @Reuben i don't know if it is exactly what u need, but i think it can helps you. I edited de post.

Comment: I think it will work like u want, u can change the value of the buttons with js or jquery, so u dont need to put 'value' in the buttom tag.

Comment: Now this is awesome! Thanks alot! You saved my ass!

Comment: @WilsondeFreitasJr.

Comment: Great! Thumbs up!